# Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I want to update the mongodb database using PUT Method. I installed method-override and included, but am still getting an error:

> Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters.

The code is below:

```
//UPDATE ROUTE 
app.put("/blogs/:id", function(req, res){
   //let id = req.params.id;
   //let newData = req.body.blog;
   Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.blog, function(err, updatedBlog){
      if (err){
         console.log(err);
         //res.redirect("/blogs");
      } else {
         res.redirect("/blogs/" + id);
      }
   });
});
```

the ejs file

```
<%- include('partials/header'); -%>

    <div class="ui main text container segment" style="margin-top: 7.0em;">
       <div class="ui huge header">Edit <%= blog.title %> </div>
       <!--HTML does not support PUT request, we have to use 
       Method-Override by adding ?_method=PUT-->
       <form class="ui form" action="/blogs/ <%= blog._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
          <div class="field">
             <label for=""><Title></Title></label>
             <!--Using value attribute instead of placehold to retrieve the data from the database-->
             <input type="text" name="blog[title]" value="<%= blog.title %>">
          </div>
          <div class="field">
             <label for="">Blog Image</label>
             <input type="text" name="blog[image]" value="<%= blog.image %>">
          </div>
          <div class="field">
             <label for="">Blog Content</label>
             <textarea name="blog[body]" id="" cols="30" rows="10"> <%= blog.body %></textarea>
          </div>
          <input class="ui violet basic button" type="submit">
       </form>
    </div>


    <%- include('partials/footer'); -%>
```

Comment: can you add the ejs file that includes the form?

Comment: That error is Mongo/BSON complaining the value you're passing in as the ID is not a string that can be cast to an ObjectID value.  What is `req.params.id`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set code as below because we are using findByIdAndUpdate so we have to set some value for the update.

```
app.put("/blogs/:id", function(req, res){
    Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        $set: {
            title: req.body.blog.title,
            image: req.body.blog.image,
            body:  req.body.blog.body
        }
    }, function(err, updatedBlog){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            //res.redirect("/blogs");
        } else {
            res.redirect("/blogs/" + id);
        }
    });
});
```